# What happens if you don't comply with BSL standards?

Tags: safety

I understand that if you work with agents regulated by the FSAP, you are required to comply with biosafety standards by federal law and there are inspections to enforce this.

But for those not working with select agents, I'm wondering what keeps them compliant.

- Do all labs at least try to follow these standards? Are there any that just choose not to?
- For those that do comply, what is their reason? Is it required to get funding? Or they're just being responsible?

Comment: Are you confusing the meaning of agent, agent means a type of material, if you are using ANY pf those materials you must comply with BSL standards under penalty of law (there is a list of exceptions for special circumstances). A list of those substances can be found here. https://www.selectagents.gov/sat/list.htm

Comment: I'm not confident enough to answer this, but I don't think there are any direct legal mechanisms to enforce BSL standards where no select agents are involved. If an employee got sick and died, the organization responsible would face wrongful death, so self-interest will promote internal enforcement.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a legal question, not one about a problem in biology.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because, as I wrote previously, it is not about a problem in biology as clearly explained in the [Tour].

Comment: What has British Sign Language to do with biology?

Answer (score 0):

You will likely get a better answer from the Law SE. I notice you didn't say which country you are in, but this will impact on which penalties there might be. I think in some cases there are international agreements that many countries have signed up to (e.g. the *[Select Agent Program](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Select_agent)* is part of one I think), but these are for high risk things in general.

However, in general, if you don't follow the law, there are punishments, just like there are for any other law breaking. What those punishments are depends on the jurisdiction you are in.

It will depend also on the severity of the infringement. In my country small infractions might get a notice to rectify, larger/continued infringements might result in personal fines (to the infringer) as well as fines for the institution and/or biological safety committee/officer, shutting down of parts (or all of the facilities at the institution), potentially even jail time for persons committing the infringements.

Of course there are people that disregard the law, just like there are people that disregard any laws you can think of. Do they get caught - YES; people and institutions get caught for this sort of thing all the time - if you search you can even find lists of more severe infractions, as these are often published for clarity.